# problem with using \metra of the metre.sty package in a footnote

Tags: footnotes

I am using XeLateX and I am trying to use the \metra{} environment of the metre.sty package in a footnote. The result is that the metrical signs I type appear correctly but in front of them appear also the signs: "▽↙′√⊔". I tried to use \metra{} two times in the same footnote. The unwanted signs appear only the first time.

Miniexample:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}

\usepackage{metre}

\begin{document}

My text.\footnote{My text \metra{\b{}\m{}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do you include `metre`?

Comment: of course, sorry, my mistake. metre in the preamble. I correct the code.

Comment: That results in a package conflict for me. Not in anything which just doesn't appear.

Comment: There is a conflict indeed, because of the definition of "breve" (./Test.tex:7: LaTeX Error: Command `\breve' already defined.) But for me the .pdf is despite this generated "normally".

Comment: Are you running XeLaTeX with `interaction=nonstopmode`?

Comment: yes, indeed, I do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55631/discussion-between-texnician-and-sschron).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to switch to the far more powerful package [`metrix`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/metrix). This supports not only better highlighting, but also works with XeLaTeX and `xltxtra`.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the issue using the fix in [memoir class and metre package incompatible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380472/memoir-class-and-metre-package-incompatible)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{metre}
\let\breve\relax

\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\rs@size@warning}[3]{\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

My text.\footnote{My text \metra{\b{}\m{}}}

\end{document}
```